# PostgreSQL - Math within a CASE

Tags: postgresql, math

I work in a small company that sells eBikes. The base product is a bike with a 4.4Ah battery. As an option the clients can choose to upgrade to a 7Ah battery. This leaves us with a product names like this:

```
eBike someName 4,4Ah restOfTheName
Upgrade 7Ah restOfTheName
```

Now I want to create a sales report using a PostgreSQL table that looks like this:

```
id | orderNumber | date | articleID | clientID | quantity | value
```

The problem that I have is that I cannot 'separate' the 4,4Ah from the 7Ah as a physical 7Ah = eBike 4,4Ah with a 7Ah Upgrade.

I want to make a `sum(quantity)` of all sold bikes based on their battery type. To do this i currently plan to use something like the following method (XXXXX to be replaced of course):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN "articles__via__bc_2018_article"."article_name" LIKE 'Upgrade%' THEN '7Ah'
        WHEN "articles__via__bc_2018_article"."article_name" LIKE '%4,4Ah%' THEN XXXXXXXXXX
    END AS "Item",
    sum("public"."bc_2018"."bc_2018_quantity") AS "sum"
```

Now my question is: Is there a way to do some Math based on `4,4Ah - Upgrade` ?

I can think of 2 more solutions to get to the wanted result:

1. Using the orderNumber: If the orderNumber of the 4,4Ah = orderNumber of a 7Ah then = 7Ah
2. Using a subquery: Select the 4,4Ah from the orders that do not include a 7Ah.

Maybe there is something else / better I can do ? (sorry i'm still a beginner)

Thanks a lot

EDIT: extra info

In the table above, the 'quantity' column is already a count. Some rows account for more than 1 item per orderNumber so it is complicated to use the `COUNT()` function and it is preferable to do a `SUM(quantity)`

Comment: So example output would be something like: `Count_4,4Ah: 23; Count_4,4Ah/7Ah_Upgrade: 4` (in the form of a table of course)?

Comment: what you want to sum? amount of rows of capacity of batteries?.. if first - use `count .. group by :Item"`, else use `sum` and use `7`, not `7Ah`... also `sum("public"."bc_2018"."bc_2018_quantity")`- no need to specify schema in sum function

Comment: @VaoTsun I want to sum the Quantity of Items sold seperating them by battery capacity. To do so I want to exclude the 4.4Ah (from the bike itemName) from the sold 7Ah Upgrade.

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox Yes that exactly it. But the 4 '7Ah _Upgrade' are not being counted within the count_4,4Ah

Comment: Okay I get your problem. I'm trying to figure out SQL right now

Answer (score 0):

Simply subtract the upgrades from the base bikes (with a subquery).

```
SELECT "articles__via__bc_2018_article"."article_name" AS "Item",
    CASE
        WHEN "articles__via__bc_2018_article"."article_name" LIKE '%4,4Ah%' THEN SUM("articles__via__bc_2018_article"."article_name") - (SELECT SUM("articles__via__bc_2018_article"."article_name") FROM Orders WHERE "articles__via__bc_2018_article"."article_name" LIKE 'Upgrade%')
        ELSE SUM("articles__via__bc_2018_article"."article_name")
    END AS "Sum"
FROM Orders
GROUP BY "articles__via__bc_2018_article"."article_name";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a stab in the dark, as I'd like to see some actual data and desired results before I jump to any conclusions.  Regardless, I think you might benefit from an intermediate step where you create a "category" column that puts each record into a finite list of possibilities.  From there, you can very quickly scale and create analytics for quantities, orders, lines, revenue, etc.

Here is a quick example of creating four categories and then running some quick analytics to find order counts for the various categories.

```
with categorized as (
  select
    a.*,
    case
      when a.article_name like '%4,4Ah%Upgrade%7Ah' then '7Ah Upgrade'
      when a.article_name like '7Ah' then '7Ah'
      when a.article_name like '4,4Ah' then '4,4Ah'
      else 'Unknown'
    end as category
  from articles a
)
select
  count (distinct order_number) filter (where category = '7Ah Upgrade') as upgrades,
  count (distinct order_number) filter (where category like '7Ah') as all_7ah,
  count (distinct order_number) filter (where category = '4,4Ah') as base_model
from categorized
```

Bear in mind, in this example the order counts overlap -- but again, that is something you have complete control over once you define the categories.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Answers above I found a little workaround.

Apparently, PostgreSQL doesn't accept a `SUM()` within a `CASE`.

That's why I have decided to use the following Sum (it's disgusting, I know - but it works) :

```
SELECT
    (SELECT 
        sum("public"."bc_2018"."bc_2018_quantity")
    FROM "public"."bc_2018"
    LEFT JOIN "public"."articles" "articles__via__bc_2018_article" ON "public"."bc_2018"."bc_2018_article" =        "articles__via__bc_2018_article"."article_id"
    WHERE (("articles__via__bc_2018_article"."article_name" LIKE '%4,4Ah%')) -
     (SELECT 
        sum("public"."bc_2018"."bc_2018_quantity")
    FROM "public"."bc_2018"
    LEFT JOIN "public"."articles" "articles__via__bc_2018_article" ON "public"."bc_2018"."bc_2018_article" =        "articles__via__bc_2018_article"."article_id"
    WHERE (("articles__via__bc_2018_article"."article_name" LIKE 'Upgrade_7Ah%'))
```